# Download epubs in Android

Tags: google-play-store, epub

So I am not sure why this is but if I upload my own books to the Play Store they do not display download links.

Is there a way maybe using an app to get the books off of the Play Store?

So here is the picture of options I see, and the book is not free and not in my purchase history either.

[image]